# SQLPlus Won't Display Columns In CSV When No Results Returned

Tags: sql, csv, sqlplus, spool

In SQL Plus I am using "spool" and "set markup csv on" to send sql SELECT queries to csv files on my computer.

This all works well enough, except when a query generates zero results, it doesn't display the column headings.  It just says 'no results returned,' but I still need it to show the column names in that case.

How can I change this?

Comment: Would adding a union with a dummy row work in your case?

Comment: That's my plan b, but it still requires me to do a lot of typing for my particular project.  I'm hoping there's a setting that can keep the header without needing a dummy row.